# Determining the if a linear transformation is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

$T : R^3 \to R^3$ defined via
$T(x, y, z) = (x + y + z, x + y + z, x + y + z)$

If I am able to say there exist $3$ eigenvalues, then I will be able to conclude that the transformation is diagonalizable. My initial thought is to form a matrix with respect to the standard basis of $R^3$ $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and row reduce to show linear dependence. Then, would I be able to conclude that this is not a diagonalizable transformation?

Comment: The zero matrix is diagonalizable (indeed it's diagonal) but its rows are linearly dependent. What tools do you know for diagonalizing matrices?

Comment: You mean 3 distinct eigenvalues. Not likely here.

Comment: The matrix is real and symmetric; that's enough to determine it's diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using the definition of a linear map being diagonalizable. Meaning that there exists a basis with respect to which the matrix of the linear map is a diagonal matrix. In this case it  is easier to diagonalize the linear map rather than to pick a basis and consider diagonalizing the matrix of $T$.

Consider the following eigenvectors and eigenvalues $$T(1, 1, 1)=(3, 3, 3)=3(1, 1,1)$$ $$T(1, -1, 0)= (0, 0, 0)=0(1, -1, 0)$$ $$T(0, -1, 1)=(0, 0, 0)=0(0, -1, 1)$$ Although we don't have three distinct eigenvalues, we do have three linearly independent eigenvectors, as you should verify.

The matrix with respect to the basis of eigenvectors $$(1, 1,1 ), (1, -1, 0), (0, -1, 1)$$ is the diagonal matrix $$M(T)=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ Thus, the linear map $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: I am a little confused how you choose the values of x,y,z in the transformation. Is this just a random choice? I see how you calculate beyond that, but where did the (1,1,1), (1,-1,0), and (0,-1,1) come from? @Seeker

Comment: @belushi1 I was just guessing values that would work. These are the first values of $x, y$ and $z$ I thought of that would work.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense thank you! Just one more quick question. I thought 0 could not be an eigenvalue and it seems that is the only reason this holds. Is that an issue? @Seeker

Comment: @belushi1 $0$ can be an eigenvalue. The zero vector can't be an eigenvector by definition of an eigenvector.